# How to install driver in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I'm VERY new to Linux and I just downloaded a driver from TP link, here is the link:

http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN823N.html#Driver

I looked in the folder but I have no idea how to install this.

I read online you can do make and make install, but it didn't work for me. I kept getting errors:

```
    "******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-28-generic/build M=/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-28-generic'
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c: In function ‘cfg80211_rtw_start_ap’:
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:3821:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat=]
   DBG_871X(FUNC_ADPT_FMT" ssid:(%s,%d), from ie:(%s,%d)\n", FUNC_ADPT_ARG(adapter),
   ^
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c: In function ‘rtw_cfg80211_rx_action_p2p’:
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:4071:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘cfg80211_rx_mgmt’
  rtw_cfg80211_rx_mgmt(padapter, freq, 0, pmgmt_frame, frame_len, GFP_ATOMIC);
  ^
In file included from /home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/include/osdep_service.h:792:0,
                 from /home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:23:
include/net/cfg80211.h:4612:6: note: declared here
 bool cfg80211_rx_mgmt(struct wireless_dev *wdev, int freq, int sig_dbm,
      ^
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c: In function ‘rtw_cfg80211_rx_p2p_action_public’:
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:4111:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘cfg80211_rx_mgmt’
  rtw_cfg80211_rx_mgmt(padapter, freq, 0, pmgmt_frame, frame_len, GFP_ATOMIC);
  ^
In file included from /home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/include/osdep_service.h:792:0,
                 from /home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:23:
include/net/cfg80211.h:4612:6: note: declared here
 bool cfg80211_rx_mgmt(struct wireless_dev *wdev, int freq, int sig_dbm,
      ^
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c: In function ‘rtw_cfg80211_rx_action’:
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:4141:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘cfg80211_rx_mgmt’
  rtw_cfg80211_rx_mgmt(adapter, freq, 0, frame, frame_len, GFP_ATOMIC);
  ^
In file included from /home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/include/osdep_service.h:792:0,
                 from /home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:23:
include/net/cfg80211.h:4612:6: note: declared here
 bool cfg80211_rx_mgmt(struct wireless_dev *wdev, int freq, int sig_dbm,
      ^
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c: At top level:
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5369:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .del_station = cfg80211_rtw_del_station,
  ^
/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5369:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_cfg80211_ops.del_station’) [enabled by default]
make[2]: *** [/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/owner/Downloads/tl_driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-28-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci`.  You may not need to compile a driver at all

Comment: It might also be useful to post the documentation which explains how to
compile and install it. From the output above, I suspect that have to run a `./configure` script before running `make`.

Comment: At first glance it looks like the driver was written for a different kernel version. And it has bugs on 64-bit platforms (at least in debugging traces). Are you sure you need to get a driver from the manufacturer? Most drivers are included in the Linux kernel, and drivers from manufacturer are usually old and unmaintained.